# Using Cumulocity add user to a group

Tags: iot, cumulocity

I've a usecase where I want to add users and devices to one group and assign roles to that group
so that a user can only deal with the devices mentioned in the group only and not other devices present in other groups.

While trying to achieve this scenario I tried making a user group (Let's say :**User_Group**) with the help of the following API

**URL**- {{url}}/user/{{tenant}}/groups(POST)
**Request Body**: {
  "name" : "User_Group"
}

After this my Group is created. Now I need to add my user(say : **Test_User**) and devices to this group.

I tried to do this using the following API:

**URL**-{{url}}/user/{{tenant}}/groups/{groupId}/users but was unable to do this as the API was give Internal Server Error.

Can anyone help me what I’m doing wrong or is there any other way I can achieve this use case?

Answer (score 0):

For group-based access control you can use "inventory roles". With an inventory role, you can specify to which groups a user has access to and what rights he needs.

Check: https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/user-and-permissions-management/#inventory